# Solutions to allowing people to change their survey answer

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

For demonstration purposes, say I have an email that goes out weekly that has red, green and blue image tiles in them. The email ask them to choose a colour. When the email recipient clicks on a colour, say red, they are taken to my ajax site and a message appears saying thanks for choosing red. The database is updated via ajax so that 'red' is incremented by 1. The page also says that they can change their mind if they like, or simply close their browser. Below this message are the three coloured tiles to click.

If the user decides they actually wanted blue and click that tile, the database decrements red by 1 and then increments blue by 1.

Now my "issue" comes with the user changing their mind. What I am doing is when the page loads and the database is updated with their choice, I am sending the unique row_id back to the page via ajax. That way if they change their mind, I simply send their new selection up to the server along with the original row_id. I decrement the original row_id by 1, and increment their new choice.

My problem is this doesn't seem very secure as the row_id is visible to the browser and end user if they wanted to see it.

Is there a better way than this? I do not want them to have to hit submit when the page first loads, I want the one click from the email to be all they have to do to register their vote. And then change their mind if they want, or just leave the page.

This is a VERY simple example of what I am actually doing, but any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, what you're doing is possibly open to a replay attack that your page could be refreshed with the same POST/GET data and cause your values to be altered by "replaying" the page. What you should do is use a unique key that gets assigned to the user -> include it in their email URL and then (when they click the link) they are taken to an intermediate page that verifies the URL key and then gives them the colour choice they selected and a confirm/change mind selection. It is here you update your database. When the database updates you invalidate the key somehow so it can't be re-used

Comment: you'd need to record individual votes, at which point it becomes trivial to change one person's vote.

Comment: The system you should employ should work like when you register an account somewhere and you get a validation link sent to your email to confirm you own the account. If you adopt a similar mechanism but take the user to the colour they originally chose and a "do you want to change your colour?" on the same page you, you could make the system work very easily if you thought about the logic.

Comment: @BigChris Unfortunately there is no possibility of adding a unique code to the URL in the email. The emails are not sent from my system, they are simply images with links around them that are inserted in to emails. Something like href="mydomain.com/red"

Comment: @MarcB I do also record individual votes, but I do the same in that I send the unique row id back down so I can ammed/update that row if they change their mind. How would it be trivial? I do not know the users voting, they are complete strangers as far as my site is concerned.

Comment: if you can't associate a voter with their vote, how could you possibly ever let them reliably change their vote> "Why yes, I did vote for red and meant to vote for blue. which vote is mine? ALL OF THEM!"

Comment: If you are unable to access much of the source code for the site you are administering then there may be very little you can do to resolve the problem you are experiencing. "Images with links around them"... Who creates the links? A simple URL such as "mydomain.com/red" will never be able to achieve what you want.

Comment: @MarcB :-) This is what I am asking for. I do currently in the manner I just explained. But obviously it is open to being abused. I was hoping there was a solution to this that I haven't thought of. Maybe a one time encryption of the row_id, encrytped using a 10 minute window or something??

Comment: @BigChris I have complete access to the site. Just not the links that are sent out that point to my site...